# annotation to specify what classes can call a method?

Tags: java, annotations

Does anyone know of an annotation in any framework or library (or IntelliJ or IntelliJ plugin) that can enforce in my code that only specific methods described in the annotation can call it?

### example

```
@caller(class="UsefulClass")
public static void myMethodToBeCalledOnlyByUsefulClass() {

}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? You already have private, protected and public

Comment: because I might forget in the future that it should be called only by that class, I can of course document it but I like the idea of a safety check

Comment: No. Seems weird. Search for 'feature envy' to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) allows you to define annotations such as `@Caller` and then have the compiler statically enforce programming rules.  You could use the Checker Framework to define your `@Caller` annotation and a compiler plugin.  Then, every time you compile your code using the plugin, it will issue an error if the code is used improperly.

The Checker Framework ships with a number of annotations already [built in](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#introduction), but not `@Caller` which you would have to define yourself.